# Javascript Accardeon menu works in iPhone 5 but not in iPhone 3

Tags: javascript, iphone, drop-down-menu

I am using a Accordeon menu from this site: http://vctrfrnndz.github.io/jquery-accordion/ and is working great. Only in iPhone 3  it cannot open any of the menus.
Is there any way to make it work in iPhone 3 too?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn´t work in iPhone 3 but it works in iPhone 5. Unfortunatelly I don´t own one so I just have to let go of this nice Accordeon menu.